# Convert []uint32 to []byte and vice versa in golang

Tags: go

What's the most efficient way (in performance) to convert `[]uint32` to and from `[]byte` in Golang?

for example:

```
func main() {
   source := []uint32{1,2,3}
   dest := make([]byte, 4 * len(source))
   // source to dest
   // ?
   check := len(dest)/4
   // dest to check
   // ?
}
```

I have a [solution](http://play.golang.org/p/BBWElfj3Jq) but it consist div, mod, and multiply

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    source := []uint32{1,2,3}
    dest := make([]byte, 4*len(source))
    fmt.Println(source)
    for start, v := range source {
       dest[start*4+0] = byte(v % 256)
       dest[start*4+1] = byte(v / 256 % 256)
       dest[start*4+2] = byte(v / 256 / 256 % 256)
       dest[start*4+3] = byte(v / 256/ 256/ 256% 256)
    }
    fmt.Println(dest)
    check := make([]uint32,cap(dest)/4)
    for start := 0; start<len(check); start++ {
       check[start] = uint32(dest[start*4+0]) + uint32(dest[start*4+1]) * 256 + uint32(dest[start*4+2]) * 256 * 256 + uint32(dest[start*4+3]) * 256 * 256 * 256
    }  
    fmt.Println(check)
}
```

Comment: 1. The factor `4` in your code suggests that you do not want a type-conversion but somehow get the raw memory of your []uint32. 2. What about endianess? 3. "the most efficient way" is not specific enough: Effizient in what sense? CPU cycles, memory, lines of code, compatibility, comprehensibility?

Comment: it's on appengine, so i don't really know what kind of machine they use, biggest possibility is little endian. efficient in term of performance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you are after something like this [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/lJYRwOt4q7)

Adjust `LittleEndian` for `BigEndian` as appropriate

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    source := []uint32{1, 2, 3}
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, source)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Encoded: % x\n", buf.Bytes())

    check := make([]uint32, 3)
    rbuf := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
    err = binary.Read(rbuf, binary.LittleEndian, &check)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decoded: %v\n", check)

}
```

Comment: A slightly different approach, it is a little bit more efficient since it saves the type assertion in binary.Write: http://play.golang.org/p/ypoFpYt2QF