# Convert [32]byte to [8]uint32

Tags: arrays, go, type-conversion, slice

I have 256 bits stored in a `[32]byte`.

I want to convert this to an `[8]uint32`, with the first `uint32` storing the first four bytes, etc.

I'm about to write a function that does this by shifting the bits into the correct positions etc, I wonder if there is an easier way to do this in Go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert \[\]uint32 to \[\]byte and vice versa in golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429885/convert-uint32-to-byte-and-vice-versa-in-golang)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using `binary.ByteOrder`

The [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package makes it easy, values of the [`binary.ByteOrder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder) interface type can be used to read `uint32` values from byte slices. There is a `binary.LittleEndian` exported variable which you can use out of the box. Put this in a simple `for` loop to read all 8 values:

```
data := [32]byte{1, 0, 0, 0, 2}
ints := [8]uint32{}

for i := 0; i < len(data); i += 4 {
    ints[i/4] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data[i:])
}

fmt.Println(ints)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rdpwmyUYg1)):

```
[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

And this of course works for any number of bytes (being multiple of 4), not just for 32.

#### Using `binary.Read()`

Another, even shorter alternative would be to use [`binary.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read):

```
func Read(r io.Reader, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error
```

This of course requires an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), for which you may use [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer). This way the conversion is a simple line:

```
data := [32]byte{1, 0, 0, 0, 2}
ints := [8]uint32{}

err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(data[:]), binary.LittleEndian, &ints)

fmt.Println(ints, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XnGv4B9r00)):

```
[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0] <nil>
```

#### Using `unsafe.Pointer`

For completeness, here's yet another, *unsafe* way. Since arrays are laid out sequentially in memory, both arrays occupy the same size. We can interpret the memory area of the input as a value of the output type:

```
data := [32]byte{1, 0, 0, 0, 2}
ints := [8]uint32{}

ints = *(*[8]uint32)((unsafe.Pointer)(&data))

fmt.Println(ints)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XSnx80KGKr)):

```
[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

This is the most efficient and the most unsafe way to solve your task.

In this case it's safe to do it like presented, but use package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) with caution and as a last resort. Many other, seemingly very similar cases might not work. We were "lucky" since we had arrays *and* input was given in little endian byte order, but with slices and / or with different byte order it would be a different story. The above presented 2 other ways are more general and work both with slices and arrays.

Comment: Since there's a constant number of elements, OP's unrolled solution _may_ be faster.

Comment: @TimCooper Maybe, but he was looking for an _easier_ way, not _faster_.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can do this using something like:

```
data_uint32[0] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[0:4])
data_uint32[1] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[4:8])
data_uint32[2] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[8:12])
data_uint32[3] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[12:16])
data_uint32[4] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[16:20])
data_uint32[5] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[20:24])
data_uint32[6] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[24:28])
data_uint32[7] = binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data_bytes[28:32])
```

Perhaps there's an even simpler way, but this will do for now.